Proving Uniform Boundedness Using Baire Category Theorem
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose for each $x$, there exists a constant $M_x$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M_x$ for all $n$. Prove that $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded on an open interval $(a, b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
My question:
How can I construct the set $I_M = \{ x \in (a, b) : |f_n(x)| \leq M_x \leq M \text{ for all } n \}$ where $M$ is a global bound for $f_n(x)$? Then, directly, result will follows by Baire Category Theorem.

The thing is, you don't necessarily need to construct the interval $(a,b)$ before applying Baire's theorem, because you can obtain such an interval as a consequence of said theorem. Also, remember that you need to apply the theorem to a countable intersection of open sets or a countable union of closed sets, but that's an easy fix since the functions are $\mathbb{R}$-valued.

Yes, so it will hold by defining first $I_M = { x \in X : |f_n(x)| \leq M = \max M_x }$ . This set is closed. Then, we have $\mathbb{R}= \bigcup_{M=1}^{\infty} I_M$, which is a countable union of closed sets. By the Baire Category Theorem, since $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of these closed sets, $\mathbb{R}$ should have a non empty closed subset $[a,b]$  without non-empty interior $(a,b)$ in $X$. And this gives us the desired uniform boundedness on $X$.

You can turn this into an answer if you'd like.

Thank you for your insights
